# Род приложений: мужской или женский?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно согласовать? Обязательно разве первое слово должно быть главным?

> Мой тыква-кот.

> Моя тыква-кот.

P. S. Что я понимаю, так это то, что, если *тыква* — главслово, надо писать так:

> Моя тыква — кот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необязательно первое слово должно быть главным.

У Вас же главенствует тыквообразный кот, а не котообразная тыква (как я понимаю). Так что кто тут хозяин, тот и барин, — согласование по хозяину.

*Мой тыква-кот.*

Пы.Сы. Что значит "Моя тыква — кот", что-то из области фантастики? Можно бы и слитно: *тыквокот*.

Comment: *Моя тыква — кот* — это *Моя кототыква*.

Comment: Согласна. Но фантастика при делах. )))